# Rails: truncate string after match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

Say I've got a string like so:

```
"This belongs to that then there's this other keyword which does something else."
```

How would I truncate it so it'd find `keyword` and truncate `keyword which does something else.` to give me only:

```
"This belongs to that then there's this other "
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1.9.3p327 > str = "This belongs to that then there's this other keyword which does something else."
 => "This belongs to that then there's this other keyword which does something else."
1.9.3p327 > str.sub(/keyword.*/, '')
 => "This belongs to that then there's this other "
```

Be careful though as this will also match on "keywordwithnotrailingspace".  Look into \b for getting word boundaries...

Comment: That seems to only trim `keyword` and nothing after it?

Comment: @emm No, it gives exactly the result you were asking for in your question.  Maybe I'm not understanding your question.

Answer (score 1):

A simple tool to add to your toolbelt is [Rubular](http://rubular.com/). You can test all sorts of awesome Regex right within your browser... Teach a man to fish ... you know the saying. :)

@emm - I think @Philip's answer is correct; however, I would use a combination of both answers and go with `keyword[.|\s]*`